# FloodFill in grid view

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a FloodFill function JavaScript this is my html code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="tools">
                        <div class="brush tool" >
                            <i class="bi bi-brush-fill"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fill tool">
                            <i class="bi bi-paint-bucket"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rangeSlide">
                        <p><span id="selectedIndex"></span> px</p>
                        <input type="range" id="indexRange" min="0" step="1" value="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pixel-grid"></div>
                <div class="right" id="colorPalette">
                    <!-- <div class="color selected" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(211,211,211);
}

.main-container{
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 20px;
}


/*---------------------Left--------------------*/
.left{
    background-color: rgb(237,237,237);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    width: 50px;
}

.tools{
    /* background-color: rgb(0, 255, 42); */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}

.rangeSlide{
    /* background-color: #ff00ff; */
    height: 100%;
}

#indexRange {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.rangeSlide{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
}

.rangeSlide p{
    position: relative;
    top: -70px;
}


/*---------------------Left--------------------*/

/*---------------------Right--------------------*/
.right{
    background-color: rgb(237,237,237);
    /* padding: 10px; */
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
}

.color{
    border: 1.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.4rem;
    width: 1.4rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
/*---------------------Right--------------------*/


/*---------------------Tools--------------------*/
.tools {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .tool {
    margin-top: 0.6rem;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.7rem;
    width: 1.7rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .tool.selected {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

/*---------------------Tools--------------------*/



.pixel-grid {
    display: grid;
    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr); */
    
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;

    
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.grid-item {
    /* background-color: white; */
    border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
}
```

javascript:

```
  // Function to check if two colors are the same
  function colorsAreSame(color1, color2) {
    return color1 === color2;
  }


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  console.log('Script loaded and DOM content loaded.');

  const myRange = {'0': 4, '1': 8, '2': 16, '3': 32, '4': 64};

  let selectedColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
  let isBrushSelected = false;
  let isDrawing = false;
  let isFillSelected = false;


  // Color array
  const colorPalet = [
    'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
    'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    'rgb(9, 255, 0)',
    'rgb(0, 174, 255)',
    'rgb(255, 0, 255)',
    'rgb(238, 255, 0)',
    'rgb(255, 123, 0)',
    'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
];

 // Get the colorPalette container
 const colorPaletteContainer = document.getElementById('colorPalette');
 


 colorPalet.forEach(color => {
     const colorDiv = document.createElement('div');
     colorDiv.className = 'color';
     colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;

     colorDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
         selectedColor = color;
         setSelectedTool(this);
     });


     colorPaletteContainer.appendChild(colorDiv);
 });





  const indexRangeInput = document.getElementById('indexRange');
  const selectedIndexSpan = document.getElementById('selectedIndex');
  const pixelGridContainer = document.querySelector('.pixel-grid');




  const numberOfItems = Object.keys(myRange).length;
  const rangeMax = parseInt(numberOfItems) - 1;


  indexRangeInput.setAttribute('max',  rangeMax.toString());




  const selectedValue = myRange[indexRangeInput.value];

  selectedIndexSpan.textContent = selectedValue;
  
  createGrid(selectedValue);

  indexRangeInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
    const selectedIndex = parseInt(indexRangeInput.value);


    const selectedValue = myRange[selectedIndex];
 
    selectedIndexSpan.textContent = selectedValue;

    console.log(`Selected Value: ${selectedValue}`);


    createGrid(selectedValue);
  });



  // Create the grid
  function createGrid(value) {
    const rows = value;
    const columns = value;

    pixelGridContainer.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            const gridItem = document.createElement('div');

            gridItem.className = 'grid-item';

            gridItem.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

            pixelGridContainer.appendChild(gridItem);
        }
    }



    // Set the grid layout styles after creating all the grid items
    pixelGridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${columns}, 1fr)`;
    pixelGridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`;
  }



  

  // Tool selection
  const tools = document.querySelectorAll('.tool');


  tools.forEach(tool => {
      tool.addEventListener('click', function () {
          isBrushSelected = this.classList.contains('brush');
          isFillSelected = this.classList.contains('fill');
          setSelectedTool(this);
      });
  });


  
  function setSelectedTool(selectedTool) {
    tools.forEach(tool => {
      if (selectedTool.closest('.left')){
        tool.classList.remove('selected');
        tool.style.borderColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)';
        tool.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
      }
    });

    if (selectedTool.closest('.left')){
      selectedTool.classList.add('selected');
      selectedTool.style.borderColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)';
      selectedTool.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    }
}
  
  // Trigger a click event on the brush tool to select it by default
  const brushTool = document.querySelector('.brush');
  brushTool.click();



//color picker
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.color');

colors.forEach(color => {
    color.addEventListener('click', function () {
        selectedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        setSelectedTool(this); // Ensure the brush is selected when choosing a color
    });
});



  //coloring
  pixelGridContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
      if (isBrushSelected || isFillSelected) {
          isDrawing = true;
          if (isBrushSelected) {
              draw(event.target);
          } else if (isFillSelected) {
            floodFill(event.target);
          }
      }
  });

  pixelGridContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    // if (isDrawing && isBrushSelected) {
    //   draw(event.target);
    // }
    if (isDrawing && (isBrushSelected || isFillSelected)) {
      if (isBrushSelected) {
          draw(event.target);
      } else if (isFillSelected) {
          floodFill(event.target);
      }
  }
});

  pixelGridContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
      isDrawing = false;
  });
  

// Draw function
  function draw(target) {
      if (target.classList.contains('grid-item') && isBrushSelected) {
          target.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
      }
  }







// Flood Fill function







  //Double click del
  pixelGridContainer.addEventListener('dblclick', function (event) {
      if (isBrushSelected) {
          if (event.target.classList.contains('grid-item')) {
              event.target.style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
      }
  });

});
```

I am trying to make a FloodFill function for a pixel grid canvas i tried multiple ways and still cant figure it out does anyone know how make this function and explain how its done? I tried to check the surrounding grid item and check there `element.style` since the style is done inline but still nothing works with me. I even tried dfs and bfs.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out this is my FloodFill function:

```
function isValidIndex(index, length) {
  return index >= 0 && index < length;
}


function floodFill(element) {
  const clickedItem = element;
  const selectedValue = myRange[indexRangeInput.value];
  const index = Array.from(clickedItem.parentNode.children).indexOf(clickedItem);
  const itemsPerRow = selectedValue;
  const gridItems = clickedItem.parentNode.children;
  const originalColor = clickedItem.style.backgroundColor;

  // Define the recursive function
  function recursiveFill(currentIndex) {
      // Check if the current index is within bounds
      if (isValidIndex(currentIndex, gridItems.length)) {
          const currentItem = gridItems[currentIndex];

          // Check if the current item has the original color
          if (currentItem.style.backgroundColor === originalColor) {
              // Change the color of the current item
              currentItem.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;

              // Recursively call the function for adjacent items
              recursiveFill(currentIndex - itemsPerRow); // Above
              recursiveFill(currentIndex + itemsPerRow); // Below
              recursiveFill(currentIndex - 1); // Left
              recursiveFill(currentIndex + 1); // Right
              // recursiveFill(currentIndex - itemsPerRow - 1); // Top left
              // recursiveFill(currentIndex - itemsPerRow + 1); // Top right
              // recursiveFill(currentIndex + itemsPerRow - 1); // Bottom left
              // recursiveFill(currentIndex + itemsPerRow + 1); // Bottom right
          }
      }
  }

  // Start the recursive flood-fill from the clicked cell
  recursiveFill(index);
}
```